# How to use videojs api?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use html5 videojs player on my site.

I am prepared example on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vCQEN/5275/

I cannot understand how to use videojs api.

Please correct my code that when click on link "start play" video begin play.

P.S.

I have found following example from :

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/api.md

```
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
  var myPlayer = this;

  // EXAMPLE: Start playing the video.
  myPlayer.play();

});
```

but I don't understandhow to modify my example. please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fiddle which work fine !

http://jsfiddle.net/vCQEN/5277/

```
var myPlayer = videojs('MY_VIDEO_1');

$('#videojsplay').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    myPlayer.play();
});
```